# How to convert extracted web data into csv file in python

Tags: python

First of all I extracted data from multiple websites using python

```python
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import traceback
pages = [str(i) for i in range(1,6)]

for page in pages:
    # Read data from url
    url1 = requests.get("https://www.top500.org/list/2018/06/?page="+ page)
    # Parse the url using BeautifulSoup
    soup= BeautifulSoup(url1.content, 'html.parser')
    #Removing an encountered special characters
    repString = "HLRS- Hochstleistungsrechenzentrum Stuttgart"
    # Finding table data in url1
    for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
        tbltxt =""
        for data in record.findAll('td'):
            try:
                tbltxt = tbltxt + data.text + ","
            except:
                tbltxt = tbltxt + replString+ ","
                pass

        print(tbltxt)
        print()
```

later on I wanted this data to convert into csv file. For this, I tried inserting following code in between for loop but encountered an error

```python
Rank= entry.Rank.text
            Rank = Rank.replace(",", "|")
            Site = entry.Site.text
            Site = Site.replace(",", "|")
            System = entry.System.text
            System = System.replace(",", "|")
            Cores = entry.Cores.text
            Cores = Cores.replace(",", "|")
            Rmax (TFlops/s) = entry.Rmax (TFlops/s).text
            Rmax (TFlops/s) = Rmax (TFlops/s).replace(",","|")
            Rpeak (TFlops/s) = entry.Rpeak (TFlops/s).text
            Rpeak (TFlops/s) = Rpeaks (TFlops/s).replace(",","|")
            Power (kW) = entry.Power (kW).text
            Power (kW) = Power (kW).replace(",","|")
            f1.write(Rank + "," + Site + "," + System + "," + Cores + "," + Rmax (TFlops/s) + "," + Rpeak (TFlops/s) + ","+ Power (kW) + "\n")
```

but got an error saying that

```html
yntaxError: can't assign to function call (<ipython-input-22-043a1b549895>, line 25)
  File "<ipython-input-22-043a1b549895>", line 25
    Rmax (TFlops/s) = entry.Rmax (TFlops/s).text
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

So, can anyone help me in getting out of this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to something like

```
Rmax_TFlops_per_s = entry.Rmax(TFlops/s).text
```

The issue is that you are trying to assign a value to a value(function call)

All these lines have the same problem:

```
Rmax (TFlops/s) = entry.Rmax (TFlops/s).text
Rmax (TFlops/s) = Rmax (TFlops/s).replace(",","|")
Rpeak (TFlops/s) = entry.Rpeak (TFlops/s).text
Rpeak (TFlops/s) = Rpeaks (TFlops/s).replace(",","|")
Power (kW) = entry.Power (kW).text
Power (kW) = Power (kW).replace(",","|")
```

**Rmax (TFlops/s)** Keep in mind that '(' ')' is not regarded as regular string characters here.

Comment: I tried but got an error stating                                                                AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-cc7f77a316d8> in <module>()
     23                 pass
     24 
---> 25             Rank= Rank.text
     26             Rank= Rank.replace(",",'|')
     27 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct syntax? Not sure about the class definition of the entry.Rank object. Looks like it doesn't have an attribute called text. Then you should try text(), which means to invoke a function called text.